# ArcGIS 10.1 ModelBuilder: Data displayed, Multiple ring buffer causes Error 999999

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, buffer, error-999999

I am trying to make a flow of processes in ModelBuilder, connecting multiple tools:

- import polygon dissolved it,
- intersected with another files, and
- selected desired polygons by attributes("ZONA" = 'A' AND
  "Shape_Area" >= 30).

  UNTIL HERE WORKS GREAT
- create buffers by **Multiple Ring Buffer**
              - **DOES NOT WORK !!!!**

I can successfully display my Selected polygons (OUTPUT).

However, when I run "Buffer" or "Multiple Ring Buffer" tools in ModelBuilder on OUTPUT , I've got back: *999999 Error executing function*.

What can be wrong with my OUTPUT data, if I can display them, but can't run the buffer analysis? And more important, how can I fix that error? Maybe save my polygons by another tool (something like Collect values ..) that would prevent the problems?

**EDIT:**

All my data have defined coordinate system, are single part polygons (results from Multipart to single part Tool), cover area max of 6000 hectares (60 km2). 
I am working on ArcGIS 10.1, Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit.

[image: Example of my flowchart]

Comment: I'm assuming that you got an ERROR 999999 (not 99999).  Perhaps review these Q&As: http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Berror-999999%5D+buffer+is%3Aquestion

Answer (score 1):

I have found the multiple ring buffer tool to be a bit flakey as it is a python script tool presumably calling ArcObjects behind the scene. These unhelpful generic error messages can often be a result of malformed geometries and the alarm bell that is going off for me is that you used the intersect tool.

You give no indication of the data you are processing (*that would have been helpful*) or the complexity of your data. Are they simple single polygons or massively multi-part, overlapping and covering thousands of square kilometres? If it is the latter you would likely need to dice up your data. For future reference you need to be *much more descriptive* about your data when trying to track down these generic errors.

I suggest you run a repair geometry tool before you attempt to run the multi-ring buffer tool.

Comment: thank you for suggestion, I have modified my question. I'll try to run the repair geometry tool

Comment: Hi, the Repair geometry tool did not work... When I start to build a new model from scratch, my script seems to work while testing, and then crashes again. Do you have any ideas what can get bad?

Comment: Could it be a write permission issue? I would test the output of your repair geometry with the buffer tool *but not in a model*. If that runs then it would suggest the tool is executing OK but your model is feeding invalid inputs/outputs/environment settings.

Comment: the repair geometry out of the model works fine... so I think that I have invalid inputs. However, I can display the inputs, does it means that they do exist at least? How can I have invalid outputs? Maybe in buffer range?

Comment: Update your question with a screenshot of your buffer tool and don't hide file paths (as some users seem to do when posting), the problem may be there? As a side note I think your question is much better now, You describe your problem, datasets, settings and show the model. It's that sort of detail people require if you are going to get an answer and is much better for people who come searching will similar issues.